# django-social-auth - Missing HTTPSConnection

Tags: python, django, ssl, python-2.7, django-socialauth

I am pretty new to Django and trying to use [django-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth) in my Django project.

I followed the [README](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth#readme) that is very clear.

my *settings.py*

```
#...

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
#    'social_auth.backends.twitter.TwitterBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY         = 'xxxxxxxxx'
TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET      = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

SOCIAL_AUTH_DEFAULT_USERNAME = 'user'
SOCIAL_AUTH_ASSOCIATE_BY_MAIL = True

INSTALLED_APPS = (
  #...
  'social_auth',
)

#...
```

If I activate the twitter backend and try to login the standard way, I get:

> 'module' object has no attribute 'HTTPSConnection'

3 questions:

- Do I have to install SSL with Python ?
- How can I check if it's installed ?
- What is the best way to install it ?

Comment: It has some dependencies, have you installed them as well? http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html#dependencies. And yes, how you installed Python, what is environment? When I compiled Python from sources on Linux I needed to install some libraries `yum install openssl openssl-devel`

Comment: I think I installed Python with `./configure && make && sudo make install`, I don't know how to upgrade or reinstall, same way ? Dependencies `python-openid` (already installed) and `python-oauth2` "can't satisfy the requirement"...

Comment: Yes, just install needed devel packages and recompile Python. What do you mean by "can't satisfy the requirement"?

Comment: pip tells "can't satisfy the requirement"

Comment: when you run `pip install oauth2`? Is there more detailed info?

Comment: "Requirement already satisfied"

Comment: Then you have all requirements installed. And PYthon with ssl support. Do you have that error about HTTPSConnection now?

Comment: Yes, actually this can be continued here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001316/python-install-openssl

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7030/discussion-between-demalexx-and-pierre-de-lespinay)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve HTTPSConnection error you need to install `openssl-devel` package, `libssl-dev` for Ubuntu, and recompile Python.