# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'OpenSSL'

Tags: python, openssl

In Python 3.6 I am getting a `ModuleNotFoundError`:

```
>>> import OpenSSL
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'OpenSSL'
```

Why can't Python find the OpenSSL module?

Answer (score 70):

The `OpenSSL` module comes from the pyOpenSSL library. You can install it with Pip using a command like:

```
pip install pyOpenSSL
```

If it fails due to missing dependencies, see the instructions on installing pyOpenSSL's dependencies in [this answer to *"How to install OpenSSL for Python"*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9001468/1709587).

(Also, as with all pip installs, depending upon your environment, you may need to write `sudo` before `pip` to run as root, and you may need to use a version-specific pip command like `pip3` or `pip2`.)

Comment: if only modules could have the same name as their pip package name

Comment: Soundtemple, please mark this answer as the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try running on a **new kernel** after installing pyOpenSSL. Sometimes when you experience `ModuleNotFoundError` even though you have installed a module, it could mean the new installation has not been updated on the currently running kernel.

Note:
If you're using a virtual environment on Jupyter Notebook or something similar, try **re-installing the virtual environment**.

For Jupyter Notebook users:

Install `ipykernel`:

`conda install ipykernel`

Re-install virtual environment:

`python -m ipykernel install --user --name <envname>`

Comment: Hi! Your answer assumes that OP uses notebook. But the questions is more general.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. My answer is to advise OP to run on a new kernel. I am not assuming that the OP is using notebook, I thought I might as well provide additional help to others who might be using notebook, which I was and had solved this issue this way.

Answer (score 0):

I went inside `/home/<username>/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages` and manually deleted PyOpenSSL related folders and ran the pip install again. It first gave an error that the version of cryptography is incompatible with this version of PyOpenSSL. I lowered the version of PyOpenSSL from 24.0.0 to 18.0.0 and this installed with no issues and the 'No module named OpenSSL' error went away.

So probably your PyOpenSSL was not installed correctly. Delete like above and re-install and look for errors during install.

Answer (score -4):

```
from OpenSSL import SSL
```

There's more context in this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30602843/how-to-import-openssl-in-python). You may also need to install pip.

Comment: -1; this unexplained one-liner isn't going to fix anything. If he can't `import OpenSSL`, then `from OpenSSL import SSL` is just going to fail with the same error.

Comment: This method worked on my side while the simple import was returning the error described.