# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'OpenSSL' despite having pyopenssl installed

Tags: python, windows, command-line, pyopenssl

I am trying to install OpenSSL for Python on windows using command line.

I have tried running the below command:

```
pip install OpenSSL
```

I got the following error:

```
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement openssl (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for openssl
```

I also tried doing it as below:

```
pip install pyopenssl
```

This succeeded but, when I try running my python script which has the below line, it shows an error:

```
from OpenSSL import crypto, SSL
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ajayv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\ENV\Scripts\PDB Latest 1250\Endpoints\X.509.py", line 1, in <module>
    import OpenSSL
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'OpenSSL'
```

Am I missing something? Please let me know.

Comment: I just installed it and it works, do you have two versions of python installed?

Comment: I used to have them....long back. But now, I have only Python 3.6

Comment: Have you checked `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: also check pip, maybe you need to use pip3 instead of pip

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError after successful pip installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32680081/importerror-after-successful-pip-installation)

Comment: Installing `pyopenssl` with `pip` should indeed allow you to `import OpenSSL`. You almost certainly have multiple Python versions (and pip versions) installed. The answer at https://stackoverflow.com/q/32680081/1709587 describes this problem and how to fix it. The specific detail that the library you're trying to install is `pyopenssl` ultimately isn't relevant here.

Comment: Potentially more relevant result for people arriving here from Google, specifically about installing `pyopenssl`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42637878/1709587